# Email Templates

Tags: email, email-template

I have created an email template and it works where an external link is embedded into it and then the data feeds back into salesforce.

This all works nicely,

What i want to do is stop people receiving the email from replying.

I know i can change my global settings to not allow email replies but we also email out of salesforce.

Is it possible to just send this email template from either a generic email address?

Kind Regards

Matt

Comment: Yes, you can define **Org Wide Email Address** using which all your emails will go.

Comment: Thanks Rohit - i dont want to change the org wide settings though... i want to be able to change the from email address to a do not reply email in the email template if possible

Comment: You can define multiple from addresses using Org wide Email Address and use specific email address for your email template for whom you don't want to receive any response. Other than this, I don't think it's possible.